# Disabling Custom Button in Excel Ribbon

Tags: office-js

Wanted to disable Custom Button added in Excel Ribbon and need to enable based on conditions.

Tried to disable custom ribbon button in manifest file itself. But there is no option for disabling. Kindly provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there isn't a way to disable a custom ribbon button. If the button is launching a Function File, consider adding conditional logic to the function. If the conditions when the function should not be available are met, the code branches to a call of the Office Dialog API and displays a message to the user saying that they can't run the function right now. The message could also suggest what they should be doing instead.